# D3.js v4+ : truncate text to fit in fixed space

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It is not uncommon to require text elements in the SVG we are manipulating via d3 e.g. categorical tick labels. This is somewhat unfortunate as the `<text>` element in SVG is not the best... The size of fonts rendered is often slightly larger than that of how much one thinks the font should take. For example, if choosing a mono-space font with a width / height ratio of 0.6 (e.g. if font size is 12px then the width of a character should be 7.2px), the element's computed bounding rectangle might be 14.2px by *n**8px where *n* is the number of characters.

Further complicating the issue is the fact that more often than not, people use fonts which are not monospaced.

It is easy enough to truncate a string which is "too long" by

```
string.slice(0, numChars-3)+'...'
```

but knowing the correct number of characters to fit within a fixed width seems non trivial.

```
function truncateText(t, text, space) {
  // make sure it is a string
  text = String(text)
  // set text
  t.text(text)
  // get space it takes up
  var rect = t.node().getBoundingClientRect()

  while (Math.max(rect.width, rect.height) > space) {
    text = text.slice(0, text.length - 1)
    t.text(text + '...')
    rect = t.node().getBoundingClientRect()
    if (text.length == 0) break
  }
}
```

the above function takes a d3.selection, the text and the space in which the text should fit in. By constantly manipulating the DOM, we can get perfect fit, however this is computationally very expensive.

To clarify, to fit text in a fix space, I mean that if I have a string `var string = "this is my very long string"`, I want the direction of the string being rendered (left to right, i.e. we are looking at string length) to fit within a fixed space (e.g. `var fixedSpace = 100 //px`)

The above truncate text function works well for just a few strings, but if there are many strings that call this function, it gets laggy.

Of course we could optimized by just picking the longest string, calculate truncateText on  that string, and take the number of characters as a result (although this is still somewhat buggy as not all characters have same width).

Is there a more efficient way to truncate text into a fixed space with d3

Comment: *"Is there a more efficient way to truncate text into a fixed space with d3?"* With D3, no. Using vanilla JavaScript, perhaps.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado text in SVG is such a pane. I guess I'll just currently use an estimated median aspect ratio for non-monospaced fonts and then add a tooltip for the truncated text :'(

Comment: You said that *"if there are many strings that call this function, it gets laggy"*. Just a curiosity: did you actually try? Did you measure it? Those browsers nowadays are insanely fast, this should not be a problem. How many strings do you have? Hundreds, thousands?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes I tried it. I had about 500+ strings of >60 characters

Comment: By the beard of Zeus, do you have 500 strings in a single datavis?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ... unfortunately yes... but I do "overflow" (see https://sumneuron.gitlab.io/d3sm/demos/bar-chart-same-data-complex-grouping/index.html) Not that it makes it any better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the approach you've suggested is computationally expensive, but it's about the only one I can think of. However if you're only running it occasionally (i.e. just on page load, rather than on mouseover), then it shouldn't be too bad, depending on how many text elements you're applying it to.

You might want to try comparing the performance of your approach to the one in [this example by Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321), which uses `node().getComputedTextLength()` instead of `node().getBoundingClientRect()` and breaks up the text by word:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

PS/ There's a [CSS technique for truncating text with an ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/), but unfortunately [it doesn't work in SVG](https://codepen.io/richardwestenra/pen/VdweWR) :(

Comment: I am aware of the CSS technique, but SVG text elements are just not as great as good old divs. I'll do a benchmark to see which is better. I am sure by dropping words at a time, that will work better on average (except when you get text from people who just hyphenate everything). I could also do a "quick sort" like approach, for handling the string length.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a 100px wide `rect` as the clipPath for your `text` element -- something like so:

```js
d3.selectAll("text.label")
  .attr("x", function(t) {
    return Math.max(0, 100-this.textLength.baseVal.value);
  });
```

```css
#text-box {
  stroke: green;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <rect id="text-box" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="1.2em" />
    <clipPath id="clip-box">
      <use href="#text-box" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
    <use x="0" y="0" href="#text-box" />
    <text x="0" y="1em" class="label" clip-path="url(#clip-box)">Long text that should be clipped</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0, 50)">
    <use x="0" y="0" href="#text-box" />
    <text x="0" y="1em" class="label" clip-path="url(#clip-box)">Another long string</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0, 100)">
    <use x="0" y="0" href="#text-box" />
    <text x="0" y="1em" class="label" clip-path="url(#clip-box)">Short text</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Update*: After the labels are rendered, use this function to get their lengths, and adjust the "x" attribute if the text is shorter than the clipping width:

```
d3.selectAll("text.label")
  .attr("x", function(t) {
    return Math.max(0, 100-this.textLength.baseVal.value);
  });
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I need to figure out how to get it to work for different text anchors, e.g. if your example were left axis ticks, then 
"Short text" would be non ideal as it should be `text-anchor:end`, but that would put the end of the text for the first two...

Comment: Ok, I've modified the example by adding a function to right-justify short text strings...

Comment: It works a moment ago, but now I do not see any text

Comment: Follow up question, why use `use`? rather than just defining the rect in defs. also with text-anchor end, this gets more messy...